# Is it possible to find the path to a loaded DLL on Windows in GO?

Tags: go

I have the following GO code:

```
package main

import (
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    var mod, _ = syscall.LoadLibrary("user32.dll")
}
```

Which successfully loads the `user32.dll` file. (This is a modified version of an example I found online).

However I do not know where on the filesystem this DLL exists. I have been searching for a way for Go to be able to tell me that through the `syscall` libs, but have not found a way to do it.

Does anyone know of a way to get the path to the DLL that was loaded?

Comment: You can use `GetModuleFileNameA ` to get the path of a loaded module, find the module handler with `GetModuleHandleA`

Comment: Searching for DLLs is similar to searching for an executable. Therefore you should be able to use https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#LookPath to find DLLs.

Comment: @yorodm Thanks very much for your suggestion, it looks very much like what I want :-). Do you have examples of how to use these functions? I think I have found them but they seem to be internal within `syscall` and I cannot access them, of course I may well be barking up the wrong tree here. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I have no access to a Windows machine running Go right now, but it **should** be something along this lines. Notice the **lack of proper resource/error management** in the code.

Please tests it and share your results so I can amend/edit my answer.

```golang
var (
kernel32, _        = syscall.LoadLibrary("kernel32.dll")
getModuleHandle, _ = syscall.GetProcAddress(kernel32, "GetModuleHandleW")
getModuleFilename, _ = syscall.GetProcAddress(kernel32, "GetModuleFileNameA")
)

func StringToCharPtr(str string) *uint8 {
    chars := append([]byte(str), 0) // null terminated
    return &chars[0]
}

func GetDllFileName() (filename byte[]) {
    var nargs uintptr = 1
    var handle uintprt
    modulename = StringToPtrChar("user32.dll")

    if ret, _, callErr := syscall.Syscall(uintptr(getModuleHandle), nargs, modulename, 0, 0); callErr != 0 {
        panic("Call GetModuleHandle")
    } else {
     handle = ret
    }
    name = make(byte[],50) // I'm making this number out of the blue
    nargs = 3
    if ret, _, callErr := syscall.Syscall(uintptr(getModuleFilename), nargs, handle, &name[0], 50); callErr != 0 {
        panic("Call GetModuleFileName")
    }
    else{
      filename = name
    }
    return
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this. Am playing with it now - will get back to you when I have something working.